# How to clean Magento enterprise large size *_cl tables

Tags: magento-enterprise, enterprise-1.14

I have magento multidomain website hosted, Automatic cleanup of such tables setting: System > Configuration > index Management > Index Clean Schedule 
is on but still the size is not reduced.

Total Domains 15, Total Products 1619, Total Orders 252320

**Tables:**

- catalogsearch_fulltext_cl         15.75G
- catalog_product_index_price_cl    15.69G
- cataloginventory_stock_status_cl  15.41G
- catalog_product_flat_cl           13.65G
- catalog_category_product_index_cl 13.43G

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me:

First take the Full DB backup,

```
1. stop cron    (SSH Command: service crond stop)

2. execute the following SQL commands to clean up changelog tables:
TRUNCATE `catalog_category_flat_cl`;
TRUNCATE `catalog_category_product_cat_cl`;
TRUNCATE `catalog_category_product_index_cl`;
TRUNCATE `catalog_product_flat_cl`;
TRUNCATE `catalog_product_index_price_cl`;
TRUNCATE `cataloginventory_stock_status_cl`;
TRUNCATE `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl`;
TRUNCATE `enterprise_url_rewrite_category_cl`;
TRUNCATE `enterprise_url_rewrite_product_cl`;
TRUNCATE `enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect_cl`;
UPDATE `enterprise_mview_metadata` SET `version_id` = 0;

3. run full reindex via shell:
php shell/indexer.php --reindexall

4. Execute the following SQL command to change saved schedule:
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '0 4 * * *' WHERE `path` = 'catalog/merchandiser/cron_setup'

5. Execute SQL command to change default schedule of enterprise_index_clean_changelog process:
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '10 * * * *' WHERE `path` = 'crontab/jobs/enterprise_index_clean_changelog/schedule/cron_expr';

6.  Start Cron
```